# How to insert system's Date into Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to insert System's Date when I at the time of insert of other values of Specified columns but it Doesn't take
the date properly.

When I fire Query separately it gives desired Date Format :

```
mysql> select date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%m-%Y') ;
+-----------------------------------+
| date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%m-%Y') |
+-----------------------------------+
| 13-06-2019                        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

But I am Unable to set System's Date at the Time of 'Insert into' Query :

### My Query :

```
INSERT INTO mems (mName, mPh1, mPh2, mAddr, mType, mJoinFee, mProtectFee, doj) 
    VALUES( 'Shubh', '1231231231', '1231231222', 'Ram janki nagar', 'S', 100.00, 500.00,
            (select date_format(sysdate(),'%d-%m-%Y') as Date) );
```

### Data Stored in Table 'mems' are :

```
+------+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| m_Id | mName | mPh1       | mPh2       | mAddr           | mType | mJoinFee | mProtectFee | mStatus | doj        | lostbooks |
+------+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------+
|    1 | Shubh | 1231231231 | 1231231231 | Ram janki nagar | S     |   100.00 |      500.00 | A       | 0000-00-00 |         0 |
+------+-------+------------+------------+-----------------+-------+----------+-------------+---------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

### Create Table Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE mems (
    m_Id int(6) auto_increment primary key,
    mName varchar(25) not null,
    mPh1 int(12) not null,
    mPh2 int(12) ,
    mAddr varchar(40) not null,
    mType varchar(1) not null,
    mJoinFee decimal(6,2) not null,
    mProtectFee decimal(6,2) not null,
    mStatus varchar(1) default "A" not null,
    doj Date not null,
    lostbooks int(1) not null default 0 
);
```

Comment: You can simply use `NOW()`

Comment: But basically a date should be entered in the format `%Y-%m-%d` i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Thanks,This worked fine. But I want to know why "date should be entered in the format %Y-%m-%d i.e. YYYY-MM-DD"

Comment: Because that is one of MySQL little rules. If the data type of the column is DATE or DATETIME

Comment: It’s easy if you think about it. If the date/time was stored any other way it would be difficult to query. Having YYYY-MM-DD allows queries in ASC and DESC order which will in turn return earliest and latest respectively. Any other format would be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Date is date, there is no need to convert it to string and then rely on implicit conversion back to date:

```
INSERT INTO mems (mName, mPh1, mPh2, mAddr, mType, mJoinFee, mProtectFee, doj) 
VALUES( 'Shubh', '1231231231', '1231231222', 'Ram janki nagar', 'S', 100.00, 500.00
       , sysdate() );
```

If you want to skip time part use `DATE(SYSDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

## `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Call a function to get the current moment on the server.

The standard SQL function [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) returns the moment when the current transaction began. It is a synonym for the MySQL-specific `NOW` function.

```
INSERT INTO mems (mName, mPh1, mPh2, mAddr, mType, mJoinFee, mProtectFee, doj) 
VALUES( 'Shubh', '1231231231', '1231231222', 'Ram janki nagar', 'S', 100.00, 500.00, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) 
;
```